# recreate activity from fragment get crash

Tags: android

I would like to re-create the activity after changing the theme To see the theme changes
I want to write the recreate() in the fragment But unfortunately, the program crashes

These are my codes:

```
MaterialDialog(context, BottomSheet(LayoutMode.WRAP_CONTENT)).show {
                listItems(R.array.skin) { _, index, text ->
                    Prefs(context).setSkin(index)
                    activity.recreate()
                }
                positiveButton(R.string.select_theme)
                negativeButton(R.string.NegativeButton)
            }
```

and this is my error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   View=DecorView@3f0a3fb[MainActivity] not attached to window manager
>           at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:517)
>           at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:426)
>           at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:126)
>           at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:389)
>           at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:371)
>           at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog.dismiss(MaterialDialog.kt:400)
>           at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.bottomsheets.BottomSheet$setupBottomSheetBehavior$$inlined$apply$lambda$2.invoke(BottomSheet.kt:133)
>           at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.bottomsheets.BottomSheet$setupBottomSheetBehavior$$inlined$apply$lambda$2.invoke(BottomSheet.kt:46)
>           at com.afollestad.materialdialogs.bottomsheets.UtilKt$setCallbacks$1.onStateChanged(Util.kt:59)
>           at com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior.setStateInternal(BottomSheetBehavior.java:1089)
>           at com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior$SettleRunnable.run(BottomSheetBehavior.java:1505)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)

Comment: Looks like a bug in the Material Dialogs library. Consider asking on their issue tracker.

Comment: First close the dialog then call activity.recreate()